# Is it possible to have a user fill out a field in an email and submit it?

Tags: html, email, templates, html-email

I am working on creating a template for a Order Confirmation and I would like to know if it is possible to include a text box where the recipient of the email could type in a sentence and submit it.

I've never dabbled in email templates, only web design and I'm not quite sure where I would start.  I'm assuming I would need to set up a server to receive the submissions, but other than that I'm clueless.

Comment: You mean you want a `form` and an `input` and a `button` in the email for the recipient to use, rather than have them reply? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Email doesn't widely support anything other than plain html and css. Forms as well as any client or server side code are not supported in most email clients.